# Solr Cloud 6.4.0 Document routing compositeID does not route to another shard

Tags: solr, routes, solrcloud

I am completely confused about what is going on in my SolrCloud setup. That said, you see I am new to the topic.

My current setup for testing is:
I have created a SolrCloud on a single server (I do not have more for testing in the moment). I use the embedded Zookeeper.
I have three shards on three nodes with two replica in each one. Every node has a different IP (8984,7574,7575).

I set up a collection with

```
curl 'http://localhost:8984/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=mycollection&numShards=3&replicationFactor=2&collection.configName=myconfigset&router.name=compositeId'
```

When I index some Documents with

```
curl 'http://localhost:8984/solr/mycollection/update/csv?update.chain=all-into-one&commit=true&separator=%09&encapsulator=%00&header=true&trim=true&f.itau_name3.split=true&f.itau_name3.separator=;&f.itau_lnx3.split=true&f.itau_lnx3.separator=;&f.itau_af3.split=true&f.itau_af3.separator=;&f.itau_init3.split=true&f.itau_init3.separator=;' --data-binary @file.txt -H 'Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8'
```

the routing works ... sometimes. It seems to depend on the prefix/compositeID I use:

When I use `r1!<uniquekey>`, `r2!<uniquekey>`, `r3!<uniquekey>` a query *:* with `_route_=r1!` returns documents with r1 and r2 prefix. `_route_=r3!` seems to be correctly routed. In the very same setup (after clearing the index and reindexing) the same with `year1!`, `year2!`, `year3!` as prefixes works. A query with `q=*:*&_route_=year1!` etc. only returns results of the respective route-prefix.

Can somebody help me to find out what's going on here?
Are there any restrictions on what how to construct the route-prefix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you did not show  your full query, but, I suspect this might be happening:

1. when you query with *route*=r1! you are not adding an fq=r_field:r1
2. *route*=r1! only tells Solr what shard to query, but this does not exclude other r field values (like r2 and r3) that are ALSO indexed in that same shard, that is why you need to add the fq

Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes. However, as I used `compositeID` as routing parameter, I do not have any r_field that I could query in a filter query (or can I? how?). Obviously, two of the three different compositeID-prefixes end up on the same shard (viz. the documents associated with these compositeIDs). But I have defined 3 shards and 3 different prefixes. Why does Solr push two of them onto the same shard and leaves one shard empty? How can I make Solr use all 3 shards?

Comment: it just happens that the hash based calculation of the shard made it so. You can always use implicit routing to decide explicitly in which shard each doc goes.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case. I now tried the whole thing with implicit routing and this works as I expected it. However, if one cannot finetune compositeID routing then what is the use case for it? Composite routing seems to be largely unpredictable.

Comment: you are supposed to use fq's along with the _route_ param as in my answer

Comment: Thus, if I understood correctly, with compositeID Solr does in effect only a rough distribution across shards? What I found puzzling is that even if there are three shards and three compositeID prefixes as in my example, I cannot be sure that Solr distributes always across all three shards. Why is this that the case? Additionally, because of this unexact distribution, I would need to add a fq along with _route_ which is not needed when I use implicit routing. Thus, is there any advantage in prefix based routing?

Comment: The why I already said, its just the hash based bucketing makes them so, check the code if you need all details. The fq is expected in all cases imho, even if it is not strictly needed in the single case where each shard is holding a single prefix. It will be needed in every other case, and even if not needed, it's better to have it for consistency.